# Rails 3, why model update fails silently ? how to debug DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I have added new fields for my devise user, but, now, I can't update the student record, although I get the message:

> You updated your account successfully.

But, the DB is never updated!

The new fields have `attr_accessible` and `attr_accessor`

Is it because there is a foreign keys in the new fields ? I have added country id to associate the user with his country, is this a reason for not updating ?

How can I debug the DB error occurred ? I tried to use `update_attributes!` in the devise function: `update_with_password`, but, no luck, no errors, just: `You updated your account successfully.`

I've noticed that there is no SQLite UPDATE command issued at Server Development log, why ?

Any help please ?

Comment: Check if the new fields are there in your DB? Are they accessible by rails console?

Comment: The fields exists in my DB, as long as there something wrong, how can I debug it ? how come no error shown ?
Also, how to check if they are accessible from rails console?

Comment: Try running the same update ie `User.first.update_attributes!(:some_attribute => 'some value')` through the script/console. Observer the output and SQL update if any generated. Also try updating the user object by directly assigning the values and calling save!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I should not use `attr_accessor` as its for those attributes that are not stored directly into DB.

I hope this will help some one.

Answer (score 0):

Try raising a exception or logging by adding an after_filter to your update action on the UserController. Try overriding the controller action (and call super) if you dont have a hook to that code.